# Using Wetty for multiple users for web application?

Tags: command-line, web-applications

I'd like to use Wetty on my Django (for exapmle) web application, basically users will be able to run "telegrambot.py" with their own token, settings for the script. So here Wetty should be great for such use case I thought.

Since it's a web application a lot of users should use it, allocating unique port number to each user is not feasible idea I thought.

```
wetty --port=3001 --command="./telegrambot.py" &  # for user A
wetty --port=3002 --command="./telegrambot.py" & # for user B 
wetty --port=3003 --command="./telegrambot.py" & # for user C
# and so on, 1000 or 10000 or more of them
```

I tried something like this also, but this didn't work

```
wetty --port=3000 --command="./telegrambot.py" --base "usera-token" &  # for user A
wetty --port=3000 --command="./telegrambot.py" --base "userb-token" & # for user B 
wetty --port=3000 --command="./telegrambot.py" --base "userc-token" & # for user C
# and so on, 1000 or 10000 or more of them
```

So, what's the best way to use Wetty for (a lot of) multiple users for web application?